# Где изменить код метода оплаты Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где поменять шаблон метода оплаты "наличными при доставке" от woocommerce, который идет стандартным? Хотелось бы вставить картинку в шаблон метода.
Папку: woocommerce/templates/checkout исщелкал, что менять - понять не могу.
Первый рисунок - без картинки.
[image: Без картинки]

Это второй, добавил для наглядности в код.
[image: С картинкой]

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: поищи по уникальному классу в IDE.

Comment: Я вчера работал с методами доставки. Я крутой спец по вордпрессу и вукоммерсу, но я полдня разбирался. Найдите специалита на фрилансе. Не трогайте сами.

Comment: Там просто может быть реально много тонкостей. Нет универсального ответа. Все зависит от кучи факторов.

Comment: @Ivan если Вы крутой спец в этом, то кто тогда я.. поиск решения занял плотного часа)

Comment: @Serj Вы молодец.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На случай если кому-то нужно будет сделать тоже самое:
шаблоны всех типов стандартных оплат по адресу: `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/`
В моем случае (именно "оплата наличными") будет здесь `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/cod/class-wc-gateway-cod.php`
Вот необходимая строка в нем: `$this->icon = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cod_icon', '' );`
Взял понравившийся значок из плагина Яндекса приема платежей, файл по адресу: `/wp-content/plugins/yandex-money-checkout/gateway/YandexMoneyGatewayCash.php` и скопировал из него точно такую же строчку: `$this->icon = YandexMoneyCheckout::$pluginUrl.'/assets/images/gp.png';` , вставил в файл способа оплаты `class-wc-gateway-cod.php` Woocommerce.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]